# PostgreSQL: labels vs columns

Tags: postgresql, performance, normalization, query-performance

I have a data structure similar to this:

```
date        foo     bar     baz     boo
----------------------------------------
2015-11-18  1       null     2.5    81.0
2015-11-19  1       78.4    12.8    null
2015-11-18  2        2.5   999.9    83.0
2015-11-19  2       null    18.0    82.4
2015-11-20  2       99.0    71.0    80.0
2015-11-18  3       32.1    18.0    null
...
```

In this example `foo` is a foreign key each row can be associated with, and date is an index. I've been thinking about two distinct ways to model this structure, and my question to people with much more database experience is which structure would be better, especially in terms of performance?

The first structure has the following columns:

```
date (int, pk)
foo (int, fk, pk)
bar (float)
baz (float)
boo (float)
```

And the other is:

```
date (int, pk)
foo (int, fk, pk)
label (varchar, pk)
value (float)
```

While the latter is better normalized, my main question is which would execute a query faster -- a particular example is finding all `baz` values when `foo == 1`.

And a final note: it is expected that the table will grow very large, with the number of individual values approaching billions in numbers.

UPDATE: Forgot to note that some values can be null.

NOTE: The only reason why I'm even considering the latter option is that it is highly likely that further columns/labels will have to be added later, and I'd like to avoid changing the schema if possible.

Comment: "While the latter is better normalized" is it? Only if at least one of bar, baz and boo can be `null`, is that actually the case? "finding all `baz` values when `foo` = 1" is likely going to be fast enough either way if you index `foo`/`value`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/31767/discussion-between-berislav-lopac-and-jack-douglas).